# How to show an intermediate page/message "Generating report" until a file is available on server in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.Net and would like your help on this,

I have a View where there is link that says 'Genererate report' when user clicks that, following action is called

```
public ActionResult RequestReportGen()
{
        String textFileWithStagedFiles = ReportsHelper.putStagedFilesToTextFile();
        String outputFile = Path.Combine(Constants.SCRATCH_DIR,Constants.REPORTS_DIR_NAME,"test.xlsx");
        String logFile = Path.Combine(Constants.SCRATCH_DIR,Constants.REPORTS_DIR_NAME,"test.log");

         // Start the child process.
         Process p = new Process();
         // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
         p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

         p.StartInfo.FileName = Constants.EXPORTER_PATH;
         p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Constants.SCRATCH_DIR;
         p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(" -textfile {0} -output {1} -log {2}", textFileWithStagedFiles, outputFile, logFile);

         p.Start();          
         p.WaitForExit();

         return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

However while the process finishes, I have to wait so that the user is shown the report when it is ready. Report generation may take couple of minutes.

Is it possible that when user click's 'Generate report' the above action is called but then he is taken to a page that shows some kind of animation of even a static page that says 'report is being generated' and once my reporting process finishes I end the intermediate page and take the user to some reporting page ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .net 4.5 you could do it in the following asynchronous manner which would allow users to continue using the site while the report is being generated and display a message using ajax rather than a separate page.

Create a method around the report generating processing that returns a task.

As an example please see below:

```
private Task RunReport() 
{
    return Task.Run(() => 
              // The below should contain your generate report code
              Thread.Sleep(5000)
     );
}
```

Then make your `Action` return a task and put an `await` before calling the report.

This will unblock the UI thread allowing users to continue using the site while the report is being generated. The content is what will be returned to page when it has finished processing.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> RequestReportGen()
{
    await RunReport();
    // Add your link to the report in the content below
    return Content("Report generated!";
}
```

Include the following javascript libraries:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then use an ajax form to post to your method, please note the `LoadingElementId` (displays when waiting) and the `UpdatedTargetId` (displays the finished message).

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("RequestReportGen", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result", LoadingElementId="loading" }))
 {
        <div id="loading" style="display:none;">Generating Report...</div>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <input type="submit" />
}
```

Using the above method your user can still use the site as your UI thread is not blocked and messages are relayed back to the user when loading and on completion.

Answer (score -1):

Create your "report is being generated" page with the following Meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://RequestReportGen/'" />

(where http://RequestReportGen is the url of your RequestReportGen method)
```

When a user visits this page, they will get redirected to the actual report page. But if it takes a while to load, then they will see your loading animation.

You could also place this in `<noscript></noscript>` tags. Then make an Ajax request to `RequestReportGen` when the page loads and replace the loading image with the generated report.